# No data from SOAP call in Java Jaxb2

Tags: java, soap, spring-boot, jaxb2

I've unmarshalled my wsdl, and placed the generated sources under the package:
generated.person

**marshaller setup:**

```
@Configuration
public class MarshalConfig {
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    //marshaller.setContextPath("generated.person");
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("generated.person");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public RKIClient rkiClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    RKIClient client = new RKIClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("https://uat.ws2.rki.dk/person.asmx");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}

}
```

**My spring boot call:**

```
public SoegPersonCprResponse getPersonWithCPR(String cpr) {
    String retVal = "";
    SoegPersonCpr request = new SoegPersonCpr();
    request.setBrugernavn(RKIClient.RKI_USERNAME);
    request.setPassword(RKIClient.RKI_PASSWORD);
    request.setCPRnummer(cpr);
    SoegPersonCprResponse response = (SoegPersonCprResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive("https://uat.ws2.rki.dk/person.asmx",
                    request,
                    new SoapActionCallback("http://webservices.rki.dk/SoegPersonCpr"));

    return response;
}
```

**response from the call is: (JSON due to the @responsebody in the webservice)**

```
"soegPersonCprResult": {
"error": null,
"person": null,
"adresser": null
}
```

But when I input the same data in SOAPui i get the following returned:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <SoegPersonCprResponse xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk/">
         <SoegPersonCprResult>
            <Error xsi:type="XmlErrorOk" xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk">
               <Code>0</Code>
               <Text>Ok</Text>
            </Error>
            <Person stamkortNr="3940982" xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk">
               <Navnedata xsi:type="PersonNavnData" beskyttet="N">
                  <Fornavne>REAL LIFE NAME</Fornavne>
                  <Efternavn>LAST NAME</Efternavn>
               </Navnedata>
               <Adresse udenlandsk="N" beskyttet="N" VejNr="1671">
                  <PostDistrikt>
                     <Navn>ADRESS</Navn>
                     <PostNr>7777</PostNr>
                  </PostDistrikt>
                  <Kommune>
                     <Kode>766</Kode>
                  </Kommune>
                  <HusNr fraNr="5"/>
                  <Vej>wildroad</Vej>
                  <Dato>27082012</Dato>
               </Adresse>
               <Foedselsdato>15111996</Foedselsdato>
               <CprStatus>AKT</CprStatus>
               <Kreditadvarsel AendretDato="23032017">J</Kreditadvarsel>
            </Person>
            <Adresser xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk">
               <StatusKode>1</StatusKode>
               <CodeMoniker>EksaktSvar</CodeMoniker>
            </Adresser>
         </SoegPersonCprResult>
      </SoegPersonCprResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you log what are you sending as request? Maybe there is the problem. Did you try with that request in the SoapUI ? Is this `SoegPersonCpr` class generated from the .wsdl of the webservice you are trying to call or is it just handmade ?

Comment: I debug, and see that the values are same in request-object and as I'm sending in SOAPui.   
They are autogenerated with jaxb

Comment: Hmm seeing the values in debug is not enough sometimes the things happen on lower level which you can not see so easy. Try putting an interceptor for seeing the exact request and response your are sending and receiving as plain String (xml) so you we can be sure that the problem is not on the our side like mapping the objects and so on. I will add simple example in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config:

```
String uri = "https://uat.ws2.rki.dk/person.asmx";

Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2 = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
jaxb2.setContextPath(request.getClass().getPackage().getName());
WebServiceTemplate ws = getWebServiceTemplate();
ws.setMarshaller(jaxb2);
ws.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2);
```

And the interceptor with the call itself :

```
    try {

        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        ClientInterceptor clientInterceptor = new ClientInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
                WebServiceMessage message = messageContext.getResponse();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {
                    message.writeTo(bytArrayOutputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String test = new String(bytArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                sb.append(test);
                // System.out.println(test);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        };
        ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[1];
        interceptors[0] = clientInterceptor;
        ws.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        final StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();                   

        SoegPersonCprResponse response =  (SoegPersonCprResponse) ws.marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request,
            new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    message.writeTo(os);
                    sbuffer.append(new String(os.toByteArray()));
                }
            });
     } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
     }
```

PS: When creating an object from type `SoegPersonCprResponse` or other that are generated from Jaxb I suggest using `ObjectFactory`

Comment: Thanks, didn't really solve it, but since I tried another unmarshaller (gradle task) problem has disapeared.
Though I really love this answer, because I really needed to see the Interceptor, and was looking for how that was done!
Thanks